# i want to update the flashdata on every ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

In my Web Application, I want to get an error message on every ajax call.
I m using CodeIgniter using I preferred to use flashdata for this purpose I came to know that flashdata don't update until the refresh

here is my ajax code

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>Auth/userlogin',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        email: email,
        password:password
    },
    dataType: 'text', 
    success: function(data) {
        var error="<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('signup'); ?>"
        if(data=='no'){
            $('#loginerror').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+error+'</div>');
        }else{
            $('#loginerror').html(' ');
            $('#login').hide();  
            location.reload();

        }


    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("some error");
    }

});
```

And here is my Controller Where I m setting Flashdata

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('signup',$this->form_validation->first_error());
        echo 'no';
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any reason whatsoever of using flash data in ajax cause you already can return any data you need in your response, in your example you can just do this:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
{
    $this->json['signup'] = $this->form_validation->first_error();
    $this->json['status'] = false;
    echo json_encode($this->json);
}
else
{
     $this->json['status'] = true;
    // your code ....
}
```

and in your success:

```
dataType: 'JSON',
success: function(data) {
    if(data.status == false) {
        $('#loginerror').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+data.signup+'</div>');
    } else {
        $('#loginerror').html(' ');
        $('#login').hide();  
        location.reload();
    }
    ...
```

Comment: i done that but it is refreshing my page id status is false

Comment: I've updated my answer, have a look at it .. make status true if there are no errors.

Comment: `{"signup":"<p>The email field is required.<\/p>\n","status":true}`

Comment: here is my response i already done that.. when i alert(data.status) it gernates undefied alert

Comment: How come there is a validation error and status is true?

Comment: Show me console.log(data) please!

Comment: here is log `{"signup":"<p>The email field is required.<\/p>\n","status":false}`

Comment: but when i do console.log(data.status) it gives undefined in console

Comment: wait wait, in your ajax function change dataType to JSON

Comment: Thankyou its working fine... but on succes instead of foing to else it is how error as `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at m.parseJSON (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Pc (jquery.min.js:4)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.min.js:4)`

Comment: You're welcome bro, there must be a syntax error in your js code, just trace it.